# How to remove extra white space in pop-up overlay and link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a pop-up that is positioned relative to the link being clicked. My code currently does this, but there is extra white space at the top/bottom of both the link that triggers the pop-up and the overlay itself. I want to remove this extra white space.

I've added borders to both the link and overlay to help you visualize the issue.

I've tried setting the link and overlay to inline-block.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #dff9fb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Endling #1</h2>
    <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/648742508&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove the extra white space at the top/bottom of both the link ('box' class) and overlay ('overlay') class. I want the overlay's positioning to remain relative to the link being clicked.

Comment: I think because you have used display flex and not aligned the items, the box has grown to fill the body - try adding `align-items:flex-start` to `.box` (or if you want the box vertically centered, instead of using margin top you can using `align-items: center`)

Comment: You know that your "whitespace" is just your `margin: 70px auto;` CSS property on class `.popup` ?

Comment: h2 {margin: 0;}

Comment: Sorry, my above comment was meant to be added to body rather than box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `flex` to align your items and by default the child elements will try to grow to the parent's (flex container) height and width.

To overcome that, you can use `justify-content` to control the way the horizontal space is distributed (you're already using this) and the `align-items` to vertically control the spacing (you need this for `.box` element to have it's original size).

Also, you're specifying a `75px` of both `top` and `bottom` `margin`s which caused the spacing in the `.overlay` element.

> There is a `margin-top` of `200px` set on the `body` that causes a scroll, it is still there in the following snippet as I *think* it is not related with you issue.

So, here's a revised version of your attempt :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /** add this so the .box div doesn't grow to it's parent height **/
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /** removed 75px that caused the top and bottom spacing  **/
  padding: 20px;
  background: #dff9fb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Endling #1</h2>
    <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/648742508&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Learn more about [`flexbox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the top/bottom margin from the pop-up and set a fixed height on the box.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 40px
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #dff9fb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Endling #1</h2>
    <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/648742508&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the margin in popup class.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.overlay {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
/*   margin: 70px auto; */ 
  padding: 20px;
  background: #dff9fb;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Endling #1</h2>
    <iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/648742508&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
    <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all your content in a html `<table>`. This should keep both boxes inline;